# Is there a faster way to find matches between two arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have this PHP code that goes through two loops to find a match:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($itemArray) - 1; $i++) 
{ 
    $item = $itemArray[$i];
    $temparray = array();

    foreach ($query3array as $resultrow)
    {                   
        if ($resultrow['custom_id'] == $item['id'])
            array_push($temparray, $resultrow);
    }

    $itemArray[$i][$columnname] = $temparray;
}
```

Can anyone recommend a faster way to do this? Going through every item in a loop every time is killing my execution speed of the PHP page.

Comment: You should go for in_array function : http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: To eliminate loop, use array_intersect function : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Comment: Have a look at he manual at array_intersect

Answer (score 0):

You should organise the `$query3array` as an *associative* array (instead of a plain indexed array), keyed by the `custom_id` values. That way you will have direct access to a row that is keyed by a certain id.

So first make that conversion to an associative array -- which I call `$hash` here

```
$hash = [];
foreach ($query3array as $resultrow) {
    $hash[$resultrow['custom_id']] = $resultrow;
}
```

Probably you should just redesign your code so that it actually *produces* such an associative array from the start. The purpose is not to go back to the indexed version you had: forget about it.

And then you only need a single loop:

```
foreach($itemArray as $i => $item) { 
    if (isset($hash[$item['id']])) {
        $itemArray[$i][$columnname][] = $resultrow;
        unset($hash[$item['id']]);
    }
}
```

This will run with a linear time complexity (even if you include the conversion) instead of quadratic one.